# How to play a youtube video with a tag in Flash Builder

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube-api, flash-builder

I am using Google code: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-samples/source/browse/trunk/ytplayer/actionscript3/com/google/youtube/examples/AS3Player.as to play a YouTube video. I want to add the tag

```
?rel=0
```

to the end of a url to prevent YouTube adds appearing at the end of the video. However, when I concatenate the tag, the following event handler no longer works:

```
playerLoader.content.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
```

For example, the following fails:

```
playerLoader.load("http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?v=wzS8ANZBRNo?rel=0");
```

but this works:

```
playerLoader.load("http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?v=wzS8ANZBRNo");
```

Can anyone suggest a way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` is used to denote the beginning of your URL vars, `&` is used to append subsequent vars.

Change:

`playerLoader.load("http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?v=wzS8ANZBRNo?rel=0");`

to

`playerLoader.load("http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?v=wzS8ANZBRNo&rel=0");`